# Dark mode on-off button with checkbox

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, addeventlistener, event-listener

Console.logs are not showing. And my functions are not working. I tried several different functions and solutions but none of them worked for me. Where is the problem can anyone help?

this my html

```
<div class="switch-toggle darkmodecheckbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="darkmodeonoff" />
              <label for="darkmodeonoff"></label>
            </div>
```

this my js;

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");
    console.log(checkbox);

    checkbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        darkmode();
        console.log("Checkbox is checked..");
      } else {
        darkmodeoff();
        console.log("Checkbox is not checked..");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you're putting the JS after the HTML code? Because if you don't then `checkbox` will be null.

Comment: omg :) you are true. thank you very much for true answer.

Answer (score 1):

bro where is your darkmode() and darkmodeoff() functions? Try add them like at the below and check out are you gonna get any alert or not? Also if you see any warning on the console, please share

```
 const darkmode = () =>{
        alert('dark')
    }
    const darkmodeoff = () =>{
        alert('light')
    }
```

Comment: comments should never be added as an answer, I remember you don't have privilege to comment due to reputation, simple solution: don't answer, just find another question that you can answer and when you get the privilege to comment just comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using `classList.toggle`:

```
checkbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      const example = document.querySelector('.containerThatYouWantUse')
      example.classList.toggle('darkModeClass')
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap code with double quotes inside code blocks, and Try using is better put outside the code block with : after it

Answer (score 0):

You can let darkmode and darkmodeoff log what you want

```
const darkmode = () =>{
    console.log("Checkbox is checked..");
}
const darkmodeoff = () =>{
    console.log("Checkbox is not checked..");
}
```

> Then call it using if statement

```
if (e.target.checked) {
    darkmode();
  } else {
    darkmodeoff();
  }
});
```